# Gradle: project depending on a Maven "child" (sub) project with dependencyManagement at parent

Tags: gradle

My (new) Gradle project depends on a Maven project that is a child of a parent Maven project with many subprojects. Notice that I only care about one little subproject there, nothing else from that parent.

Trouble is, Gradle walks up the Maven project tree and when it sees the "dependencyManagement" in parent pom instead of treating it for what it is - list of "approved versions" of dependencies for any and all subprojects of that parent, it actually assumes that they are ALL *actual* dependencies of the child/subproject I care about... And that brings waaaay too much stuff into my Gradle project.

I am presently working around by explicitly excluding all those dependencies I *presently* know are not *presently* (again) not needed, but I don't want to do that as that would mean that I have to keep up my project essentially in sync with *ALL* projects from that parent.

This is with Gradle 1.6. I *MAY* have some (little) level of influence on how those Maven projects are structured but preferably such a thing would not be needed and I could somehow tell Gradle to behave as it should... Is there a way?

Please help!

*EDIT 1*

- The dependency is via a maven repository. The dependency I have is a subproject of a project built and deployed by Maven, to a Maven repository.
- I also asked this on Gradle forums: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/8mftwmyn8uu75?rfm=1

Comment: How do you make the Maven module available to Gradle? Have you checked the Maven module's effective POM?

Comment: Via maven repository. I depend on the artifact of a project that is built by Maven and deployed to a Maven repository.

Comment: I haven't heard of Gradle interpreting the `dependencyManagement` section as actual dependencies before. My best guess is that something is wrong with the POM and/or parent POM, but without seeing them it's hard to say.

PS: Please don't double-post here and on http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce with "org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE" (which declares "org.springframework:spring-parent:3.1.4.RELEASE" as its parent), but it works as expected. To investigate further, I'd need a self-contained reproducible example.

Comment: You're right. I had a more thorough look at an extremely long pom of that parent project and therein were actual dependencies listed. So my bad (their bad) in other words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was not a problem at all. Huge POM of that parent project was hiding some actual dependencies that exploded...